# Suppress cart items from email recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I would like to remove the products that are in the cart from email recommendations.
How can we do this in Salesforce Marketing Cloud / Einstein?

Thanks in Advance!!
Nikhila

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this, email recs do NOT exclude items in the cart for the profile/email, you could include `?cart=ITEM1|ITEM2|ITEM3` which would exclude these items from the rec call. And Rule Manager also wouldn't be able to achieve this use case

```
<td>
      <a href="https://XXXXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/YYYYYYY/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?cart=1234|5678|9012">
        <img src="https://XXXXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/YYYYYYYY/i/1/%%emailaddr%%?cart=1234|5678|9012">
      </a>
    </td>
```